# ERROR: CustomerTrigger: execution of BeforeUpdatecaused by: System.ListException: Duplicate id in list:

Tags: apex, trigger, list, before-trigger

I have written one trigger on before update.
On customer object -before edit i need to save changes in Test_c object.

```
   trigger CustomerTrigger on Customer__c (before update){
    list<test__c> updateTest=new list<test__c>();
    if(trigger.isupdate && trigger.isbefore){
        for(customer__c cust:trigger.new){
            test__c t=new test__c(id=cust.test__c,salary__c=cust.salary__c,phone__c=cust.phone__C);
            updateTest.add(t);
        }
    }
update updatetest;
}
```

It is working for single and  multiple customer records if Test lookup is different for each record.
But if 2 customer havinf same test lookup then trowing below error.

```
ERROR: CustomerTrigger: execution of BeforeUpdatecaused by: System.ListException: Duplicate id in list: a1O28000007ZypIEASTrigger.CustomerTrigger: line 10, column 1
```

Please suggest

Comment: If two customer will have the same test lookup then updateTest will be filled with duplicate test__c. Thats why you are getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the test__C id's to a set and filtering it out inside the for loop would fix this issue.

Your code can be modified as

```
trigger CustomerTrigger on Customer__c (before update){
    list<test__c> updateTest=new list<test__c>();
    Set<Id> testIdSet = new Set<Id>();

    if(trigger.isupdate && trigger.isbefore){
    for(customer__c cust:trigger.new){
        if(!testIdSet.contains(cust.test__c)) {
            test__c t=new test__c(id=cust.test__c,salary__c=cust.salary__c,phone__c=cust.phone__C);
            updateTest.add(t);
            testIdSet.add(cust.test__c);
        }
    }
    }
    update updatetest;
}
```